# How to do version-control repository update in crontab?

Tags: ssh, cron, cvs

I'm trying to automate version-control repository update in crontab.  The following script `/home/usr/mrbean/bin/update.sh` works in interactive Bash command-line:

```
#!/bin/bash

ROOTPATH="/home/user/mrbean/temp/"
cd $ROOTPATH
SSHTMPFILE="${ROOTPATH}ssh-agent.cf"
ssh-agent -s | head -n 2 > "$SSHTMPFILE"

function killsshagent {
    /bin/kill $SSH_AGENT_PID
}
trap killsshagent EXIT


if [ -f "$SSHTMPFILE" ]; then
    source "$SSHTMPFILE"
    ssh-add
    rm "$SSHTMPFILE"
fi

killsshagent

if [ `hostname` == "mrbeancomp.local" ]; then
    REPODIR="/home/usr/mrbean/repo/"
    cd $REPODIR
    cvs update -dP  > "$HOME/log/log.txt"
fi
```

I then add

```
@hourly /home/usr/mrbean/bin/update.sh
```

The script works by itseful when invoked in interactive Bash shell but not via crontab.  It gives errors and sent to system mail `/var/mail/mrbean`:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).
cvs [update aborted]: end of file from server (consult above messages if any)
```

#### [Update]

`killsshagent` added in program so `ssh-agent` is not dangling.

#### [Update]

Tried an adapted program on a Git repository and experienced same issue. Mr. Bean isn't allowed to immediately abandon this CVS repo and switch to a new Git one.

#### [Update]

I have multiple identity files in `$HOME/.ssh/`.  Is it possible that when running from crontab, I need to specify which identity file to use?  If so, how?

Comment: For the love of god, use something besides cvs. It's 2014.

Comment: @Faheem, your comment is irrelevant.

Comment: As irrelevant as it might seem, he's actually right - modern DVCSes are much better integrated with ssh. But that's not the main reason for abandoning cvs.

Comment: Try running the `ssh` in verbose mode - `ssh -vvv`. That should give you some indication of what is wront with the authentication. Given the error, I suppose the script is running under the correct user, but you might want to double-check. Also note, that you are spawning new `ssh-agent` instance every time the script runs and don't kill them.

Comment: How do I "running the ssh in verbose mode"?  Change `ssh-agent` in the above to `ssh-agent -vvv `?  I added `kill` so `the ssh-agent` process is killed.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess (I'm not a unix expert, but have had a similar issue with cron jobs not running), what user are you executing the task as? Does that user have all the permissions needed to access everything you need?

I suspect not (the error sort of says so! :-D ).

If you logout from the working user and log in as a different user, does the bash script work still? If not, then that does sort of help.

The solution we used was to run the task as a specific user.

There are several ways to do this it seems (aren't there always). I can't comment on the merits of one over the other - that will be for you to decide.
[How to specify in crontab by what user to run script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475694/how-to-specify-in-crontab-by-what-user-to-run-script)